# Custom UITableviewCell label position

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a custom cell with a couple of labels. I want to have 1 label exactly at the right position as if i would use a UITableViewCellStyleValue1. The idear is that i have only 1 Custom Cell with more data inside and the rest of the table should use UITableViewCellStyleValue1. My Problem is that the margins are not correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The custom cell was created with IB. 
Edit: Added a simple example.

The right margin of "**Lets go!**" is not the same like "**More text**". The Margins between the Header and Footer is also not correct. The Cell within section 1 is a custom cell with 4 labels. I'm not using auto layout. I hope this will clear things up.

The Text for **Lets go!** can be dynamic. Meaning it will be set by code.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more details. How did you create your custom cell? Code or IB? Post relevant details.

Comment: post your image if you have

Comment: i will prepare an example screenshot and attach it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're not using auto layout**

1. Go into interface builder and access your custom cell's xib file
2. Add a UILabel
3. Click on the UILabel and then position it to the far right
4. With your label selected, click on the `size inspector` tab on the right navigation pane
5. Then click on the auto resizing box and click the right handle and make sure its highlighted in red like shown in this picture below:

[image: List item]

Notice how the left handle is unselected but more importantly the right handle in the autoresizing box is selected. This is important as it tells the UILabel to hug to the right of the View and retain its position no matter how much the view is expanded or contracted.

**If you are using auto layout**

1. Click on your UILabel
2. Click on the `pin` tab where the four buttons are positioned at the bottom of your interface builder screen (shown in the image below)
3. Now you will see a pop up box (also shown in the image below), click on the cross hair's `right handle` at the top of the popup window (next to the textfield where it says `20` in the image below), and the handle will turn red. This will add 1 constraint to your label and ensure it maintains that constraint
4. Now click on `Add 1 Constraint`

[image]